# Failed building wheel for ldap Failed to build ldap

Tags: python

I was installing ldap and python gave me an error:
`(venv) root@dns:/opt/web/powerdns-admin# pip install ldap
Collecting ldap
Downloading ldap-2.0.0.404.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: ldap
Building wheel for ldap (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for ldap (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [103 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
------------------------------------------------------------------------
# `ldap` on PyPI

````
  This dummy project is not installable.
  You probably want `python-ldap` instead.
  
  
  ### python-ldap
  
  The widely used [python-ldap](https://python-ldap.org) project provides
  an importable module named `ldap`.
  
  This goes against the convention that PyPI distribution names should
  match the module names.
  But, python-ldap pre-dates wide use of that convention, and the issue
  is hard to fix now.
  
  Please install `python-ldap` to get the LDAP bindings.
  
  
  ### ldap 1.0
  
  The `ldap` name on PyPI was used for an unrelated collection of
  LDAP-related utilities, which is not as popular, and confused users who
  install `ldap` to get the `ldap` module.
  
  The project is no longer developed.
  It is archived as `1.0.x` releases on PyPI, and on
  [GitHub](https://github.com/andreif/ldap).
  
  
  ## Why we don't fix this transparently
  
  This could have been a placeholder  package that depends on `python-ldap`,
  saving you the trouble of reading this message.
  
  However, `pip` [has trouble](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4961)
  with differently-named packages that provide the same module.
  
  
  ## Please: Don't install packages blindly
  
  When you see the exception:
  
  ```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
  ```
  
  … please research the actual requirements instead of going directly for
  `pip install foo`.
  The project (distribution) name may differ from the module(s) it
  provides.
  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/web/powerdns-admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/web/powerdns-admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/opt/web/powerdns-admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ydftf5z_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 18, in run
  ValueError: "ldap" is not installable. You probably want python-ldap.
  [end of output]
````

ERROR: Failed building wheel for ldap
Failed to build ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: Welcome to S/O! The output clearly says `"ldap" is not installable. You probably want python-ldap.` Have you looked into that?

Comment: Also, the markdown description provides a lot of valuable information.